How can I switch between buttons on a dialog box using the keyboard without activating Full Keyboard Access?
I'd like to switch between buttons on a dialog box using the tab key, just like in Windows (any other key or combination instead of tab is OK).
I don't want to use Full Keyboard Access because I hate the blue outline it shows around each component and also the fact that I can't use the tab key to insert tabs in texts any more.

Welcome to Ask Different, Alex. You might care to let us know what you tried, link to  a specific Apple support article explaining the shortcut you tried? You could explain if you’re on an Apple TV device, iPad device, iPhone or Mac. All of them have keyboard control and all of them have dialog boxes. Even better, show us a dialog or name a specific app and list what version of which OS you have.

Have you already looked into customizing FCA to see if you can do what you want?    https://support.apple.com/en-eg/guide/mac-help/mchlc06d1059/mac#:~:text=Turn%20on%20Full%20Keyboard%20Access,turn%20on%20Full%20Keyboard%20Access.

Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question. But I recall that this was an option somewhere in System Preferences many OSX versions ago. I found it very useful. I don't see it in System settings but perhaps someone knows how to set this preference in Terminal?

Open System Settings -> Keyboard -> Turn on Keyboard Navigation
